# Efficiently Synchronizing Python Project Environment Across Multiple Hosts with SaltStack

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a Python project named 'test' located in /home/user/projects on a salt-master host. I've successfully used file.recurse to distribute this project to three different hosts. The project runs within a virtual environment created by pyenv.
Now, I'm facing a challenge in synchronizing the project's virtual environment across these hosts. Initially, I considered using file.recurse to sync the entire .pyenv directory to the other hosts, but this approach is resource-intensive. I also thought about packaging the entire .pyenv, but I'm not convinced it's an optimal solution.

Is there a more efficient method to distribute the project while simultaneously synchronizing the project environment? I'm looking for a solution that avoids excessive resource usage and ensures that the Python environment is consistent across all hosts. Any advice or alternative approach would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar with SaltStack, but I assume you have the ability to execute commands on hosts. The [pip-tools package](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/) provides a simple tool to sync the local environment with a `requirements.txt` file.